# adding resources on a new resource file

Tags: android, xml, android-studio, android-layout

new to android studio, and i get stuck over what seems the most simple things, i would love some help:

on my activity_main.xml file, i noticed i use a value (0.9) several times, and i thought it would be better to change it to read from a resource rather than using hard coded number on each one.

i created a file called numbers.xml under my res/values folder, and after failing to refrence the value i got the following code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources xmlns:ns1="http://schemas.android.com/tools" xmlns:ns2="urn:oasis:names:tc:xliff:document:1.2">
    <integer name="aaa">8</integer>
    <item name="guideline_perc" type="dimen">0.5</item>
    <float name="number">0.9</float>
    <dimen name="num2" type="float">0.6</dimen>
</resources>
```

it appears i can only refrence the first value, example:

```
 app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="@integer/aaa"
```

however i want to refrence the other values, not the integer, how do i do that?
the only thing i can come up with is that this property only get integer numbers, but it doesn't make any sense because only 0.x would show the button this property is part of, on the screen.

any help is appreciated.

thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To reference the other values you defined in your numbers.xml file, you need to use the appropriate type when referencing them.

For example, to reference the "guideline_perc" value of type "dimen", you can use the following syntax:

```
app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="@dimen/guideline_perc"
```

And to reference the "num2" value of type "dimen", you can use:

```
app:some_property="@dimen/num2"
```

Make sure to use the appropriate type when referencing your values, as using the wrong type can result in unexpected behavior.

Comment: i genuially can't believe it - i did it before posting, and it showed me error. I have honestly no idea how come it now works. ty.

however, is 'float' not a valid type in those?
when trying to compile with the <float> tag i got this error:

 Can't determine type for tag '<float name="number">0.9</float>' 

is this not a type?

Comment: Sorry, the float or double parameter can be stored as string and then get it using Double.parseDouble.

Comment: i dont think i can use this on the xml file, but apprantly i can use the <string> tag to do what i wanted. didn't think it'd work.

Comment: If I have helped you, I thank you for accepting the answer. All the best